# How can I fade out the ui text when enable it false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveGameMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    public float speed;
    public bool startFading = false;
    public bool enableText = false;

    private Color textColor;

    private void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        textColor = text.color;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (startFading == true)
        {
            if (enableText == true)
            {
                text.enabled = true;
            }

            textColor.a = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
            text.color = textColor;
        }
        else
        {
            text.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And using it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayingInGameScenesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook[] freeLookcameras;
    public LockController lockController;
    public GameObject uiSceneText;
    public GameObject player;
    public float transitionSpeed = 5f;
    public float thresHold = 0.1f;
    public bool talkingProcess = true;
    public SaveGameMessage saveGameMessage;

    private bool newGame = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public void PlayingSceneInGame()
    {
        PlayingSceneStatesControls(true);
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayingTime());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && newGame == true)
        {
            PlayingSceneInGame();
            newGame = false;
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
       
    }

    private void PlayingSceneStatesControls(bool LockState)
    {
        lockController.LockControl(LockState);

        if (LockState == true)
        {
            uiSceneText.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            talkingProcess = false;
            uiSceneText.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayingTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        PlayingSceneStatesControls(false);

        freeLookcameras[0].enabled = false;
        freeLookcameras[1].enabled = true;

        var brain = Camera.main.GetComponent<CinemachineBrain>().m_DefaultBlend.m_Time;

        saveGameMessage.enableText = true;
        saveGameMessage.startFading = true;

        player.GetComponent<Player>().SavePlayer();

        StartCoroutine(FakeSave());
    }

    IEnumerator FakeSave()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);

        saveGameMessage.startFading = false;
    }
}
```

At the bottom I'm making fake for 7 seconds the problem is when the fake finish the ui text enable false at once.  In the SaveGameMessage script at the bottom I'm doing :

```
text.enabled = false;
```

but that is ugly it's just stop the fade in out effect at once. I want somehow to enable it false but before that to finish the current fading so the text enabled false will be smooth fading out and ot just suddenly stopping the fading effect.

Answer (score 0):

Before you disable it run an animation to fade it out. this animation should first be made or maybe you can find one online.

then just run the animation before setting it to false.